# Building code on Remote

Tags: linux, remote, cuda

I have a Linux (Mint) PC with a Nvidia GPU, which i want to make into a CUDA build server.
I want to write my CUDA code on a different (if possible Windows) machine and build it on the server.
So to summarize I want to:

- Write my code on a client
- Connect to my server
- Transfer the source code to my server
- Build it there
- Run it on server
- Copy it back to the client machine

My question is how do I all of this in a hassle free way and if possible in a single step (by only running a single command)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just create easy `.bat` and shell scripts that execute all these steps one by one. Use ssh/putty/rsync/ftp/NFS for upload/download procedures.